# how to keep button's border displayed and after click other area it goes away

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Just like the effect on the documentation, but it is an a-tag, which has to be use href attribute. 
I have two questions
1.for pseudo-class a-tag to serve as a button, how do I prevent it from jump to # block. 
2. If I use button class, after first click it first time, how to keep it in focus state, and then after click it second time, it will go back original state...

```
.btn,.btn-primary{
    width: 110px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: black !important;
    background-color: white !important;
}

.btn,.btn-primary:active,.btn,.btn-primary:focus{
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    border-color:#4477b1 !important;
    border-width: 2px !important;
}
```

this is my html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-4 active" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="true" (click)=display()>{{buttonContent}}</button>
```

this picture shows after first click
[after first click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRUes.png)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding from your question is that you don't want the button outlined **all** the time (because you do that by just adding a border)....but that you instead want it outlined like that **after** initial click and to **not** be toggled off if you click elsewhere **except** on the button itself. If I misunderstood let me know and I will edit as needed.


Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ebtk1oqg/

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
      .btn,.btn-primary{
        width: 110px;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        color: black !important;
        background-color: white !important;
      }

      .btn-primary:focus {
        box-shadow: none;
      }


      #btn-primary.focus {
        box-shadow: none;
      }


      .is-active {
          box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2rem rgba(38,143,255,.5) !important;
      }


  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="yourButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-4 active" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="true" (click)=display()>buttonContent</button>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $('#yourButton').click(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("focus active");
            $(this).toggleClass("is-active active");
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```